# How can I reduce boot up time to display xsession as soon as possible?

Tags: 12.04

I am using ubuntu-12.04-armhf(presize) on ARM platform. I am running a xsession on it. My current booting time is 13 sec. I want to reduce it to as less as possible.
   Please, I need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ...buy an SSD??

Comment: @Sparhawk I have class-10 SD card and ubuntu-12.04 is booting from that SD card.

Comment: Fair enough. I know of some programs that work out what gets loaded first at startup and moves them to the faster sectors of platter hard disks, but that is not appropriate in this case. I guess a more generic answer is to remove some of the daemons that are unnecessary. What desktop environment are you using? I know that in KDE there is a "services configuration" that lists all daemons etc.

Comment: @Sparhawk I am using LXDE-slim desktop environment.I removed unnecessary daemons also and now getting 11.58 sec booting time.Thank you for the help. If you know any tweak please suggest me. Because I am still not happy with 11.58 sec.

Comment: That's about all I can think of. I guess 1.5 seconds is better than nothing! :)

Comment: @Sparhawk But I am not satisfied with 11.5 sec. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Sometimes, you just need to accept the limitations of your hardware. :)

Comment: Anyway, I put up my suggestion as an answer, just to formalise it.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove some of the daemons that are unnecessary. Your desktop environment might allow an easy way to configure this. For example, in KDE there is "services configuration" that lists all daemons etc., and allows you to disable specific ones.

Comment: I installed rcconf package and I disabled all unnecessary daemons still I am getting booting time 11.40 ms.

Comment: To be honest, I'm surprised you are getting even this much reduction! I would have thought the core system would be an even larger proportion than this. Another option, depending on your needs, is to not use a desktop environment at all, but a super slim window manager such as awesome http://awesome.naquadah.org/ . Warning: it's hardcore. :)

Comment: Thnk you, I will try this. :)